# Problems installing Meteor.com with curl

Tags: curl

Having problems using curl on a new Mac (OS 10.7.4), with curl 7.25.0 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5.

Worked fine on my previous system, but now I am receiving the error:

curl: (2) Failed initialization

Anytime I try to grab anything. For example:

curl www.example.com

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem after installing Mountain Lion. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678085/curl-48-an-unknown-option-was-passed-in-to-libcurl/11680443#comment15512061_11680443