# Ruby installatation curl: (48)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I'm trying to install ruby on rails on my Ubuntu 12 PC. 
I use the steps described here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

at the step:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

i get the following error:
curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl

I tryed to reinstall curl, but I get the same error.
Thank you!

Comment: what do you get when you run `curl -L https://get.rvm.io` by it self ( aslo without the first slash)?

Comment: Run `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -x -s stable` (with `-x`) option. It will trace received bash script. Then post output of this command here. It will help to investigate your problem.

Comment: for     curl -L https://get.rvm.io  -> I get the same error    curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl

Comment: for curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -x -s stable     I get the same

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678085/curl-48-an-unknown-option-was-passed-in-to-libcurl