# "curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl"

Tags: linux, http, curl

After I build curl from source On ubuntu 16.04 machine, when I test curl like this:
curl http://google.com
An error message saying:

> curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678085/curl-48-an-unknown-option-was-passed-in-to-libcurl)

Answer (score 0):

*Solution from OP.*

1. use curl -V to show the version of libcurl that curl uses.

**curl 7.56.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.56.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8.**

if your libcurl version is less then curl version then this type of error might be come.

2. open  /usr/local/lib and copy libcurl.so.4 and libcurl.so.4.5 or above
3. and then override(pest) the old libs in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
4. now lets check again curl -V and if your curl version is updated then your problem is fixed.